# Route53 route to cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am struggling to route with route53 to a cloudfront distribution

I have a domain registered with AWS. For this example, let's call it "mydomain.com"

Steps I have made:

- create and validate certificate in us-east-1 region (registered for *.mydomain.com)
- add certificate arn to cloudfront distribution
- add alternate domain (CNAME): cloudfront.mydomain.com
- configure "cloudfront.mydomain.com" as type "A" record in route53 and make it point to the cloudfront distribution

I made all the steps then to test if it was succesffull I do following

```
dig cloudfront.mydomain.com
```

However I do not get the cloudfront distribution entry? What am I doing wrong?

These steps are as in AWS documentation and as other users described in how to setup custom domain for cloudfront

Any ideeas?

I get following back from dig command

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> cloudfront.mydomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55826
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cloudfront.mydomain.com.        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
cloudfront.mydomain.com. 51 IN   A       54.192.233.53
cloudfront.mydomain.com. 51 IN   A       54.192.233.71
cloudfront.mydomain.com. 51 IN   A       54.192.233.83
cloudfront.mydomain.com. 51 IN   A       54.192.233.43

;; Query time: 10 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.100.1#53(192.168.100.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 13 10:00:21 EEST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 123
```

Shouldn't I have been able to see the cloudfront distribution domain in the dig response?

I see the IP's above are for cloudfront, but I expected to also see the domain of the distribution, since that's what's mentioned in AWS documentation

Comment: You’re almost there! In Route53 configure `cloudfront.mydomain.com` as an **ALIAS** of your CloudFront distribution.

Comment: What do you get after executing `dig cloudfront.mydomain.com`?

Comment: I'm getting following
```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
cloudfront.mydomain.com. 51 IN   A       54.192.233.53
cloudfront.mydomain.com. 51 IN   A       54.192.233.71
cloudfront.mydomain.com. 51 IN   A       54.192.233.83
cloudfront.mydomain.com. 51 IN   A       54.192.233.43
```

I'm a little bit confused here. Shouldn't I have seen the cloudfront distribution domain here since now it is working? (I have an ALIAS set in route53)

Answer (score 0):

In case it will help anyone. The issue was the cloudfront distribution had ipv6 enabled and I used an A record for the alias. I disabled ipv6, now it seems to be working.

For ipv6 we need to configure AAAA record alias